# How to get run time dimensions of a div on applying resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have  div which have resize function applied on it.
When I resize the div and refresh the page ,It retains the same old dimensions.
What i need is ,It should retain the resized value even after refresh.
Are there any ideas to achieve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#box").resizable();
  $('#main').draggable();
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "-") {
      $(this).html("+");
    } else {
      $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="title_bar">
    <div id="button">-</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <marquee direction="right">
      <h4>Hi user</h4>
    </marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use sessions in java script to store previously set values and set it to the div on page load.
Is that what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SessionStorage for this. And if you want this to persist between different sessions use localStorage. Below is the code and a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e73e3ux0/1/)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e73e3ux0/2/)

```js
$(function() {
  var wid = window.sessionStorage.getItem("boxWidth");
  var hit = window.sessionStorage.getItem("boxHeight");
  if (typeof wid != 'undefined' && typeof hit != 'undefined') {
    $('#box').css('width', parseInt(wid));
    $('#box').css('height', parseInt(hit));
  }
  $("#box").resizable();
  $("#box").on("resize", function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("boxWidth", $("#box").css('width'))
    sessionStorage.setItem("boxHeight", $("#box").css('height'))
  })
  $('#main').draggable();
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "-") {
      $(this).html("+");
    } else {
      $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="title_bar">
    <div id="button">-</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <marquee direction="right">
      <h4>Hi user</h4>
    </marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If i want to apply alsoResize function on multiple divs then what can i do?

Comment: as of now you are using`#box` selector that targets an id. if you want to target more than one div. use a class selector i.e give same class to all divs an the use `$(".box").resizable();` this will make all divs with class `box` resizeable. and then if you need to store all their values you will have to keep a unique name for each div becuase sessionStorage store values in key value pairs and for every div key should be unique

Comment: Yaa this issue is resolved now i am back to that if i required dimensions of a div dynamically & arrange other divs accordingly.How to do that.Suppose i have diff divs on the screen in the form of tiles & if i resize a div than arrange other tiles accordingly.

Comment: `display:inline-block` that what you need. Inthis case divs will automatically adjust their position based on each others width and height. HAve updated the fiddle with the code to show how it will look like.